# Google Apps Script, The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>"

Tags: html, google-apps-script, html-parsing

My goal is to create a program that will grab the tables received via gmail & append them to an existing google sheet.

The first portion of the project is to grab the tables from the gmail; thus I've written the following code:

```
 function getEmail (){
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('test');
  var threads = labels.getThreads();
  for(var x=0;x<threads.length;x++){
    var msg = threads[x].getMessages();
    for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
      var subject = msg[i].getBody();
      var date = msg[i].getDate();
//      var xml = subject + "</meta>" ;
//      var xml = "<root>" + subject + "</root>" ;   
      var doc = XmlService.parse(subject);
      var content = doc.getAllContent();
      Logger.log(date)
      Logger.log(content)
    }
  }
 }
```

The error that I'm getting is as follow:

```
Exception: Error on line 32: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
getEmail    @ Code.gs:11
```

I've traced the solution to either: adding a '  ' end tag or adding a '/' to the header tag. How can I accomplish either of those?

This is the current HTML meta tag on all the messages returned:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<meta content="en">
```

Update-
I tried using the GOS html parser library; but I get the same error.

I need guidance on how to find the meta tags and modify them.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like your missing an opening  `<meta>` tag

Comment: `XmlService.parse` of Google Apps Script does not work well. You should consider i) using a parser libray, ii) create your only parser, or iii) [extract with regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Checkout Cheerio library for GAS.

Comment: I'm missing a </meta> closing tag. But it isn't required in HTML. So that i means I need to add : 1) a closing meta tag , 2)a '/' to the opening tag as <meta/> is acceptable

Comment: I used another parser library (Gas); and I get same error. So it still points to the need of adding the closing meta tag to the html object